# Set timeout on get location request

Tags: java, android, gps

In a Java Android app I have a method that gets the GPS location of the device. In certain places, the `onLocationChanged()` callback happens after several minutes from the request, so the coordinates aren't accurate. How can I set a timeout (lets say 5 seconds) and after that period to cancel the request?

In C# I can do that pretty easy by setting the `Timeout` property:

```cs
public async Task GetCoords()
{
    try
    {
        var location = await _geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest
        {
            DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Best,
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
        });
        
        Longitude = location.Longitude;
        Latitude = location.Latitude;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", $"Error reading gps\n{ex.Message}", "OK");
    }
}
```

How can I do that in Java? After request should I start a delayed task that stops the request after the timeout period?